# Accuracy doesn't increase in Binary Classification with 3D coordinates as data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, keras, machine-learning-model, accuracy

I have 4000 catalogues of galaxies, in each there are 34700 objects, for each of it I have x,y,z coordinates. I want to do a binary classification creating a model which should be able to determine which catalogues have a particular value of a Cosmological parameter and which catalogues have another value of the same parameter. 
The two types of catalogues are labelled differently (0 and 1).

The full program is available here:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n7jDwu8ekqDl3OmYY2R49J55CUMraY9K

The accuracy doesn't improve during the training: here is the main part of the code:

```
python
# So far we have a numpy array (train_data) with shape (4000, 34700, 3):
# 4000 catalogues, 34700 objects (galaxies) in every catalogue, 3 coordinates for every object
# Now I'm going to turn this array in a (4000,104100) array by concatenating the three coordinates

train_set=np.zeros((4000,104100))
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    train_set[i]=np.concatenate((train_data[i][:,0],train_data[i][:,1], 
                                 train_data[i][:,2]))
    if (i % 250==0):
        print('Flattening '+str(i)+'th mock')

# Build the model

model=keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

#Create a validation set

x_val0=train_set[:100]
x_val1=train_set[1000:1100]
x_val2=train_set[2000:2150]
x_val3=train_set[3000:3150]
x_val=np.concatenate((x_val0,x_val1,x_val2,x_val3))

partial_x_train0=train_set[100:999]
partial_x_train1=train_set[1100:1999]
partial_x_train2=train_set[2150:2999]
partial_x_train3=train_set[3150:3999]
partial_x_train=np.concatenate((partial_x_train0,partial_x_train1,
                                partial_x_train2,partial_x_train3))

y_val0=train_labels[:100]
y_val1=train_labels[1000:1100]
y_val2=train_labels[2000:2150]
y_val3=train_labels[3000:3150]
y_val=np.concatenate((y_val0,y_val1,y_val2,y_val3))

partial_y_train0=train_labels[100:999]
partial_y_train1=train_labels[1100:1999]
partial_y_train2=train_labels[2150:2999]
partial_y_train3=train_labels[3150:3999]

partial_y_train=np.concatenate((partial_y_train0,partial_y_train1,
                                partial_y_train2,partial_y_train3))

#Train the model

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20,
               batch_size=200,validation_data=(x_val, y_val),verbose=1)
```

I have tried with different combinations of Dense keras layers, but here's the result:

```
Train on 3496 samples, validate on 500 samples
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/20
3496/3496 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 2/20
3496/3496 [==============================] - 7s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 3/20
3496/3496 [==============================] - 6s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 4/20
3496/3496 [==============================] - 6s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 5/20
3496/3496 [==============================] - 6s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

And so on until the end.

Comment: my first recommendation is to try to put the dropout layer before each dense layer, and the second one is to try using CNN to train your data?

Comment: Thank you, I'll now try to follow both of your suggestions, I'll let you know if they work!

Comment: Have you tried other techniques besides those from keras? Sometimes simpler models have better results